# substitute period from abbreviation (single letter + period) unless followed by a capital letter

Tags: regex, r

I want to sub out periods that follow a single letter; so `t.` becomes `t` & `p.m.` becomes `pm`.  If this happens > 1 time in a row I'd like to remove spaces that happen in between; so `e. g.` becomes `eg`.  If the `single letter + period` occurs more than 1 time in a row followed by 1-2 spaces and a capital keep the period unless the capital is followed by a period.

- Sub out periods after single letters (regardless of case)
- Get rid of optional space between > 2 occurrences
- If occurs > 1 time in a row followed by 1-2 spaces and a capital keep period

  - Unless the capital is followed by a period

## MWE

```
x <- "Mr. Brown comes! I met at 7:30 p. m.  I will go at 5 a.m. eastern time or @ 2 p. m. I live in the U. S. A. I met John P. Jones later."

# my attempts
gsub("(?<=(\\b[A-Za-z]))(\\.)(?! {1,2}[A-Z])", "", x, perl = TRUE)
gsub("(?<=(\\b[A-Za-z]))(\\. )(?! ??[A-Z])", "", x, perl = TRUE)
```

## Desired Outcome

```
"Mr. Brown comes! I met at 7:30 pm.  I will go at 5 am eastern time or @ 2 pm. I live in the USA. I met John P Jones later."
```

Comment: If I got your rules correctly, shouldn't `P. Jones` remain the same and not change to `P Jones`?

Comment: I back up the suggestion to keep the period after `P` in `P. Jones`. What about https://ideone.com/Omko9b?

Comment: @ndn I think `If occurs > 1 time ` covers this but I might not have explained it clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

`(?:(?<=[a-z])\.\s(?=[a-z]\.))|(?:(?<=[a-z])\.)(?!(?:\s[A-Z]|$)|(?:\s\s))|(?:(?<=[A-Z])\.\s(?=[A-Z]\.))|(?:(?<=[A-Z])\.(?=\s[A-Z][A-Za-z]))`

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/qP4kR3/1)

For R use:

`"(?:(?<=[a-z])\\.\\s(?=[a-z]\\.))|(?:(?<=[a-z])\\.)(?!(?:\\s[A-Z]|$)|(?:\\s\\s))|(?:(?<=[A-Z])\\.\\s(?=[A-Z]\\.))|(?:(?<=[A-Z])\\.(?=\\s[A-Z][A-Za-z]))"`

Comment: This indeed works.  I'll hold off on the check in case people have more efficient regexs.  Thank you.

Comment: I think this can be made more efficient with `\p{L}`, `\p{Lu}`, and `\b`.

Comment: @stribizhev. I also think my solution isn't the better. I answered just cause it works. But I would be glad in see other ways.

Comment: I'd like to see an optimized approach as well though @WashingtonGuedes provides a very usable solution.